# React Native - Get which touchable highlight is selected

Tags: javascript, react-native

Just trying to get the current index of the touchable highlight that is pressed. For some reason it is only returning the highest number in the array. Any ideas?

```
render: function() {
    var images = [], i = 0;

    for(i=0; i<this.props.picturesList.length; i++){
        var currentIndex = i;
        images.push(
            <TouchableHighlight
                key={'c' + i}
                onPress={() => this._handleItemTouch(currentIndex)}>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={{uri: this.props.picturesList[i]}} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }
},
_handleItemTouch: function(index) {
  console.log(index);
}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try using let to declare the currentIndex variable. I is being incremented all the way up to the last value in the array + 1, let will scope the variable to what it is in the context of the loop:

```
for(var i=0; i <this.props.picturesList.length; i++){
        let currentIndex = i;
        images.push(
            <TouchableHighlight
                key={'c' + i}
                onPress={() => this._handleItemTouch(currentIndex)}>
                    <Image
                        style={styles.image}
                        source={{uri: this.props.picturesList[i]}} />
            </TouchableHighlight>
        );
    }
},
```

I set up a demo [here](https://rnplay.org/apps/TB3KqQ).

Comment: Thank you. That was a rather dumb mistake by me.